# AngularJS ng-repeat not working with $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a basic page, which I can define json data manually in scope, and everything works fine.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ordersApp">
<head>

<scrip src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.15/angular.js"></scrip>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Recent Orders</h1>
<table ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<tr>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Stock Description</th>
<th>Order #</th>
<th>Order Value</th>

</tr>


      <tr ng-repeat="item in orders track by $index">
        <td>[[item.oh_statusdate]]</td>
        <td>[[item.ol_stockdesc]]</td>
        <td>[[item.oh_orderno]]</td>
        <td>[[item.oh_ordervalue]]</td>

    </tr>

</table>

 <scrip>

// register the app
var ordersApp = angular.module('ordersApp', []);
// alllow [[var]] instead of {{var}} for jinja2
this.ordersApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) { 
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[['); 
          $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        });
// create a controller inside the app
ordersApp.controller('orderCtrl', function ($scope) {
    // assign the json data
  $scope.orders = [
              {"ol_stockdesc": "EALANT", 
              "oh_statusdate": "2014-07-02", 
              "oh_custaccref": "416", 
              "oh_ordervalue": null, 
              "oh_orderno": 449605}, 

              {"ol_stockdesc": " BAG 25kg A", 
              "oh_statusdate": "2014-07-04", 
              "oh_custaccref": "416", 
              "oh_ordervalue": null, 
              "oh_orderno": 449824}, 

              {"ol_stockdesc": "BOTTLE B", 
              "oh_statusdate": "2014-07-04", 
              "oh_custaccref": "416", 
              "oh_ordervalue": null, 
              "oh_orderno": 449824}, 

              {"ol_stockdesc": "CREDIT CARD ADMIN & SURCHARGE", 
              "oh_statusdate": "2014-07-04", 
              "oh_custaccref": "416", 
              "oh_ordervalue": null, 
              "oh_orderno": 449824}
              ];
});
</scrip>

</body>

</html>
```

The above works fine, however if I try doing the following:

```
// register the app
var ordersApp = angular.module('ordersApp', []);
// alllow [[var]] instead of {{var}} for jinja2
this.ordersApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) { 
          $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[['); 
          $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        });
ordersApp.controller("orderCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://0.0.0.0:6543/orders.json?customer=416').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.orders = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

It doesn't work, I can inspect the request with dev tools and see the data request is made successfully, and also inspect $scope and my data is in there, the console also doesn't log any errors. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated. Please note due to my firewall I cannot post  tags, so my example code is shown as "scrip" instead of "script".

Comment: Is the json _exactly_ the same?

Comment: yes, exactly the same.

Comment: Are the `<scrip>` and `</scrip>` tags a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to surround your `$scope` change with `$apply`? Like this:

```
$scope.$apply($scope.orders = data);
```

The reason could be that once in your clojure, the `$scope` scope don't have the same meaning.

A way to avoid doing this is to use `$resource` instead of `$http` as it would use a future and will populate nicely your array at the end of the request

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this sadly did not work. Again, my data still showed inside $scope.

Comment: Ok :( Even in the data is in $scope, $apply should have sent the right event and force a redraw of the ng-repeat.

Comment: I think it might be a slight difference in the JSON the server has generated via python, just investigating.

Comment: If you can, copy the response from your server using developer tools and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As per Andy Gaskell's comment, I triple checked my JSON and the server was adding extra quotes and backslashes in one place, I swiftly fixed this and now my old code works perfectly.